# ssh-add permanently a key without asking passphrase

Tags: 14.04, ssh, ssh-agent

I have a private key with a passphrase

And I have 2 computers running Ubuntu 14.04

- On the first I added the key using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
  It asked me the passphrase, and it was added permanently.
- On the other when I add a key using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` it is asking me the passphrase and adding it temporarily (it will be removed at the next reboot).

But all others ssh keys without passphrase are added automatically.

I have tried the solutions explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/add-private-key-permanently-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu

But it doesn't work. And I really don't see how it could work (despite the positive feedbacks).

I don't see how just defining our SSH key as a "IdentityFile" in the SSH config files would make it automatically add the SSH keys with passphrase. It would mean that when I do a ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa the system is storing the passphrase somewhere, but using it only if I add "IdentityFile" in the config. And for ssh key without passphrase it doesn't need any "IdentityFile".

Does someone knows how ssh-add work on this? How can the ssh-add behaviour can be so undeterministic?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to add a key with passphrase permanently. The encrypted key is stored in the memory of `ssh-agent`, which is not persistent across the reboots.

The keys in default location or the keys mentioned in `~/.ssh/config` (without passphrase) do not need to be added to the agent. The `ssh` will pick them up automatically.

Comment: Ok, thanks but what about the keys (with passphrase) that seems to be added permanently to my first computer? Because I am rebooting it and the SSH keys are there and I can use them to connect

Comment: You are using probably gnome-keyring, which might do something like that.

Comment: Linux Mint XFCE 19.3: I created a new RSA key with seahorse.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was the problem.
It seems like it is gnome-keyring and seahorse that are adding it ti the ssh-agent

And **seahorse need the public key (.pub) to be in .ssh** (next to the private one) in order to automatically add it